# Expectation of $\cos(X+Y)$ given $X$.

Tags: probability-theory, trigonometry, conditional-expectation, exponential-distribution

Let $X$, $Y$ be independent and exponentially distributed with mean $1$. Find $\mathbb E(\cos(X+Y)\mid X)$.

What I did:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E(\cos(X+Y)\mid X) &= \mathbb E(\cos X \cos Y-\sin X\sin Y|X) \\&= \mathbb E(\cos X \cos Y|X)-\mathbb E(\sin X \sin Y|X) \\&= \cos X \mathbb E(\cos Y|X)-\sin X \mathbb E(\sin Y|X)
\end{align*}
Is this correct? I am not sure we can open it like this or not. Does this imply that $\cos X \cos Y$ and $\sin X \sin Y$ are independent?

Comment: Yes, you can use the sum rule for cosine, then use additivity of expectation, then use the fact $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Note that by definition, $\Bbb{E}\{f(X,Y)|X\}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Bbb{E}\{f(X,Y)|X=x\}f_X(x)dx$. Are you able to find $\Bbb{E}\{f(X,Y)|X=x\}$?

Comment: Can u please explain how we will find that?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz That does not look right. I think it should be something like $E[g(X,Y)\mid X]=\int g(X,y) f_Y(y)\, dy$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom, apparently the definition depends on context. For example, some resources (including https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation) present a definition as $\Bbb E\{g(X,Y)|X\}=\Bbb E\{g(X,Y)|X=x\}$, but an information theoretical definition uses a similar definition to mine for conditional expectation, entropy and mutual information. It is much better however, for the sake of clarity, to denote $\Bbb E\{g(X,Y)|X\}$ with $\Bbb E\{g(X,Y)|X=x\}$ if it is to be taken that way (as in this question).

Comment: Using the additivity of $\Bbb E$ does not imply the summands were independent. Rather, factoring $\cos X$ and $\sin X$ out of the $\Bbb E$ used the fact $X$ and $Y$ are independent. And it looks like their independence gives you one final step OP: replace $\Bbb E[\cos Y\mid X]$ with $\Bbb E[\cos Y]$, and similarly for $\sin Y$.

Answer (score 1):

What you did so far is correct: the first equality is just $\cos(a+b)=\cos a\cos b-\sin a\sin b$, the second one the linearity of conditional expectation and the third one is the pull-out property, since $\cos X$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable as well as $\sin(X)$.

Then $\mathbb E(\cos(Y)\mid X)$ can be computed thanks to independence: this is simply $\mathbb E(\cos(Y))$, and similarly, $\mathbb E(\sin(Y)\mid X)=\mathbb E(\sin(Y))$ and these expectations can be computed explicitely.

I do not see why what you did implies that $\cos \cos $ and $\sin \sin $  are independent.